# QByteArray во float

Tags: qt, float

Есть QByteArray, в котором лежат несколько float. Нужно их оттуда вынуть и записать в соответствующие переменные. Пока единственным решением нашел копирование области памяти с помощью memcpy:

```
float f1, f2;
memcpy(&f1, byteArray.data(), sizeof(float));
memcpy(&f2, byteArray.data()+sizeof(float), sizeof(float));
```

Если пытаться использовать QDataStream, то ничего путного не выходит, т.к. он пытается считать не 4 байта, а 8. Какие решения еще можно найти?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте класс [QDataStream](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html) и `setFloatingPointPrecision()`.

```
QByteArray arr;
float f1, f2;
QDataStream ds(&arr, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
ds.setFloatingPointPrecision(QDataStream::SinglePrecision);
ds >> f1 >> f2;
```

Чтобы попеременно читать `double` и `float`, нужно переключать режим точности.

```
QByteArray arr;
float f1;
double f2;
QDataStream ds(&arr, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
ds.setFloatingPointPrecision(QDataStream::SinglePrecision);
ds >> f1;
ds.setFloatingPointPrecision(QDataStream::DoublePrecision);
ds >> f2;
```

Либо можно читать "сырые" байты:

```
QDataStream ds(&arr, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
ds.readRawData(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&f1), sizeof(f1));
ds.readRawData(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&f2), sizeof(f2));
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. А если в QByteArray лежат и float и double, есть какое-нибудь похожее решение?

Comment: @nulll обновил ответ.